# Forcing proper charset encoding of the filename of uploaded file in Play 2.0.4

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework-2.0, windows-server-2008, forms

I have annoying problem with non-latin characters in names of uploaded files. I'm using upload method pretty similar as in the [Play's doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFileUpload) (extended by DB operations) and while running `dist` vrsion on the unix machines, everything is OK. In Windows - which is a production server - non-latin characters are damaged, for an example:

```
return ok(uploadFile.getFilename());
```

gives me: `zaÅ¼Ã³Å‚Ä‡_gÄ™Å›la_jaÅºÅ„.png` instead of `zażółć_gęśla_jaźń.png`

How can I avoid this and/or force reading and writing filenames always with the same encoding?

**Edit**

I just discovered, that when starting app with `play start` (instead of `dist` + `start.bat`) filename is written properly... that just confuses me even more o.O

Answer (score 0):

The working solution is forcing it while starting the jar in the start.bat script by adding param:

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```